# firebase realtime database on("child_added") function not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to print all firebase realtime database inputs out in my div tag using this code:

```
function courserep(name, course, matno, current_level){
firebase.database().ref("students/"+course+"/"+matno+"/result/"+current_level).on("child_added", function(snapshots){
        var html = "";
        html+="<div id='level'>";
        html += "<p id='redmi'>"+snapshots.val().name+"</p>";
        html += "<input type='number' id='grade'>";
        html += "<button id='rebtn' onclick='hlevelii()'>ADD RESULT</button>";
        html += "</div>";
        document.getElementById("enteroo").innerHTML+=html;

    })
}
```

i tried this code block, and like i said i am expecting it to get all the particular pushed files from the database

Comment: If you `console.log("students/"+course+"/"+matno+"/result/"+current_level)` right before you attach the listener, what path does it output? Does your database indeed have data at that path?

Comment: What is the difference between the two code blocks you posted?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen my database has the path, it locates the path

Comment: the two code blocks are same i was asked to explain the problem again, please if theres a way you an assist, i'd be grateful

Comment: If the system asks you to explain the problem better, please don't just repeat the same information. :-/

Comment: On the path: please edit your question to show the updated code (with the new `console.log` statement), its output, and the JSON at that path in the database (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).